# How can I animate simultaneously all the graph points inside Manim?

Tags: graph, manim, algorithm-animation

I made this class : 50 points of a spiral change to a cirle.

But the animation is sequential and I would like to start it at the same time.

```
class SpiralToCircle(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        vertices1 = range(50)
        vertices2 = range(50)
        edges = [(48, 49),(3, 4)]
        g1 = Graph(vertices1, edges, layout="spiral")
        g2 = Graph(vertices2, edges, layout="circular")

        # self.add(graph)
        self.play(Create(g1))
        self.wait(5)
        for i in vertices1:
            self.play(g1[i].animate.move_to(g2[i]))
        self.wait()
```

I thought about this trick, but I returns an error :

```
self.play((g1[i].animate.move_to(g2[i])) for i in vertices1)
```

**TypeError: Unexpected argument <generator object GraphCircular.construct.. at 0x00000229667509E0> passed to Scene.play().**

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `self.play([g1[i].animate.move_to(g2[i]) for i in vertices1])` The play function can take a list of animations.

Comment: It returns a Typerror : TypeError: Unexpected argument 
   [<manim.mobject.mobject._AnimationBuilder object at 0x0000016B6E1E04C0>, <manim.mobject.mobject._AnimationBuilder object at 0x0000016B6E1E0EE0>,
<manim.mobject.mobject._AnimationBuilder object at 0x0000016B70204D60>, <manim.mobject.mobject._AnimationBuilder object at 0x0000016B70204DF0>, <manim.mobject.mobject._AnimationBuilder
object at 0x0000016B70219160>] passed to Scene.play().

Comment: I believe the way you do the move_to breaks it. Try just .move_to instead of animate.move_to

Answer (score 0):

Try unpacking the animation list and pass them as parameters to the play method:

`self.play(*[g1[i].animate.move_to(g2[i]) for i in vertices1])`

So, the code would be:

class SpiralToCircle(Scene):

```
def construct(self):
    vertices1 = range(50)
    vertices2 = range(50)
    edges = [(48, 49), (3, 4)]
    g1 = Graph(vertices1, edges, layout="spiral")
    g2 = Graph(vertices2, edges, layout="circular")

    # self.add(graph)
    self.play(Create(g1))
    self.wait(5)
    self.play(*[g1[i].animate.move_to(g2[i]) for i in vertices1])
    self.wait()
```

Generating this output:

[Output Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGxpw.gif)